# JEE Advanced 2018-Question on Application of Derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [-2,2]$ is a twice differentiable function with $f^2(0)+(f^{'}(0))^2=85$. State whether it is true or false that:
There is $x \in (-4,4)$ such that $f(x)+f''(x)=0$ but $f'(x)$ is non zero.
Now, I went as far as this. I took a function $T(x)=f^2(x)+(f'(x))^2$.  Clearly, its derivative is $2f'(x)(f(x)+f''(x))$. Now by applying LMVT in $(-4,0)$ and $(0,4)$, we can find $u \in (-4,0)$ and $v \in (0,4)$ such that
$$\frac{f(4)-f(0)}{4}=f'(v)\leq 1$$(use the codomain of $f$) and similiarly, we have
$$\frac{f(0)-f(-4)}{4}=f'(u)\leq 1$$. So, in both the cases, $T(x)\leq 4$ for $x=u,v$. Thus, quoting ivt and rolle's theorem, we can find a value $a$ in $(-4,4)$ such that $T'(a)=0$. But we still have to show that $f'(a)$ is non-zero. How can we show it? Is this even possible?Is it even necessary?If not please contradict with an example.

Comment: Here $f^2(x)$ stands for $f(f(x))$ or $(f(x))^2$? I suspect it's the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f'$ is continuous and $|f'(0)| \ge 9$ so say wlog $f'(0) \ge 9$ (change $f \to -f$ which preserves the hypothesis and conclusion or if you like, apply the argument below with $-9, -1$ and note that the $v$ you find above actually satisfies $-1 \le f'(v) \le 1$ etc) and consider the set of points in $[0,4]$ where $f'(x)=1$ nonempty by IVT and your argument with the existence of $v$ above with $f'(v) \le 1$ and take $c$ its infimum so $f'(c)=1$ by continuity and
$f'$ cannot be zero on $[0,c]$ as you would find a closer $c_1$ to $0$ where $f'(c_1)=1$ by IVT again.

Similarly find $-d$ so $f'(-d)=1$ and $f'$ cannot be zero on $[-d,0]$ and then $T$ must attain its maximum inside $[-d,c]$ at some $a$ since $T(0) > T(-d), T(c)$ and $f'(a)$ cannot be zero by our choices of $c, -d$, while $2f'(a)(f(a)+f''(a))=T'(a)=0$ there and you are done!.

Comment: It was really wonderful. But I would ask you how you came across this? Was it a bit of guess work combined with proof? How did you get the hint? I mean this was a bit hidden. I wanted to see the heuristics.

Comment: The issue was the potential vanishing of the derivative - otherwise your work would have been sufficient; but $f'$ continuous and large at $0$ means it must pass first through $1$ (or $-1$ if large negative) before reaching zero on either side so it must be first non vanishing on either side and your work applies there; the rest is just formalizing that into a rigorous argument